# Any issues with yaktrax and flat pedals

Tags: ice

Did anyone tried using [yaktrax](https://www.yaktrax.com/product/walk) ice-traction device for shoes when using bicycle (with flat pedals)?

I have noticed that often very large risk of falling in icy conditions is when mounting dismounting, and yaktrax seems like it could be of help in such situations. Anyway I am concerned if yaktrax might tangle into the pins of the pedal and lock my feet.

Comment: Certainly getting your foot tangled is a danger.  You'd have to study the particular cleats and the particular pedals together to determine how serious the danger is.

Comment: Well, I was hoping to hear first hand experience if someone has already tried. I am recovering from broken ankle, and I would like to put my risks to minimum, while still using my bicycle.

Comment: @DavorinRuševljan, first, get hight shoes/boots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yaktrax and simila all increase the risk of a tangle. However, one must test with your specific shoes, cleats and pedals to see how high the risk of entanglement is. That risk must then be evaluated against the risk of slipping when dismounted.

Another alternative is to use studded shoes. They are harder to use together with toe clips than normal shoes because you can not slide your shoe on the pedal. The risk of entanglement, however, should be pretty nonexistent.

Instead of buying studded shoes you could also buy threaded studs such [as these from Bestgrip](http://www.best-grip.se/bestgrip-3000/16-0) and screw them into your normal cycling shoes.